# Creating a loop in R which also changes the column name

Tags: r, loops

I am attempting to loop a command based upon a list (fish_species). And while I’ve found plenty of examples, I haven’t found one that also includes changing the column name as part of the loop.  I have figured out how to get the desired result for an individual species (lines 10-13), but in the actual dataset I have ~500 species, and I’d prefer not to repeat this command 500+ times. Is there a way to substitute the values from a list where it says variable?

```
Fishdata$variable <- ifelse(fishdata$Species== “variable”,fishdata$Number,0)
```

I know how to do this is ArcGIS, but I am trying to expand my horizons and learn R. This is also my first post, so please excuse any screw ups. 
Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
fishdata <-c()
fishdata$Site <-c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
fishdata$Species <- c("one_fish", "two_fish", "two_fish", "red_fish", "blue_fish", "blue_fish")
fishdata$Number <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
fishdata$one_fish <-0
fishdata$two_fish <-0
fishdata$red_fish <-0
fishdata$blue_fish <-0
fish_list <- c("one_fish","two_fish", "red_fish", "blue_fish")
fishdata$one_fish <- ifelse(fishdata$Species=="one_fish",fishdata$Number,0)
fishdata$two_fish <- ifelse(fishdata$Species=="two_fish",fishdata$Number,0)
fishdata$red_fish <- ifelse(fishdata$Species=="red_fish",fishdata$Number,0)
fishdata$blue_fish <- ifelse(fishdata$Species=="blue_fish",fishdata$Number,0)
```

Comment: Kind of difficult to figure out what you want. Can you provide an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` to iterate over species,

```
sapply(fishdata$Species, function(i)ifelse(fishdata$Species== i, fishdata$Number,0))

#     one_fish two_fish two_fish red_fish blue_fish blue_fish
#[1,]        1        0        0        0         0         0
#[2,]        0        1        1        0         0         0
#[3,]        0        1        1        0         0         0
#[4,]        0        0        0        1         0         0
#[5,]        0        0        0        0         1         1
#[6,]        0        0        0        0         1         1
```

Comment: An interesting approach, unfortunately I just want one column for each species. This produces multiple columns for several of the species (two_fish, blue_fish).

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand what you mean. If you add the expected output in your question then It should be clearer.

Comment: Sotos, I've added a couple of lines to the original code to get it to produce a table in the desired format. Hopefully that helps demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: hmm...try changing `sapply(...)` to `lapply(...)`

Comment: This continues to produce too many columns, it seems to be transposing the data. There should only be as many columns as there are fish species (4).

Comment: oh, then try wrapping it with `unique`, i.e. `unique(lapply(fishdata$species,...)))`

Answer (score 0):

`$` is just an alternative to the `[]` operator:

```
a$x
a["x"]
```

So you can do:

```
fishdata[species] <- ifelse(fishdata$Species == species, fishdata$Number, 0)
```

---

```
for (species in fish_species) { 
    fishdata[species] <- ifelse(fishdata$Species == species, fishdata$Number, 0)
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works _as is_... and not sure if it can be done vectorized. I'd wrap this solution into a loop like `for (species in fish_species){ ... }`. Apologies if it was implicit in your answer that this went into a loop. Wasn't completely clear to me where the OP was planning on having his loop, so just thought it could be helpful to clarify.

Comment: Yes, this would be the in the body of a loop.

Comment: When I adapted the code you provided I got the following error message: Warning messages:
1: In fishdata$Species == fish_species :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In fishdata[fish_species] <- ifelse(fishdata$Species == fish_species,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @K.Lott did you add it into a loop? That error can occurs when you put the answer directly into your code replacing `species` with `fish_species`. That was the clarification about the loop that I was referencing...

Comment: Gabe: I am looking up how to use the "For" command now. But if someone just wants to give me the answer and write out that line of code I won't object. :)

Comment: @sdgfsdh, first of all I want to thank you for your attempts at helping me. On Friday I attempted the code you provided but, it repeatedly gave me the following error: 1: In fishdata[species] <- ifelse(fishdata$Species == species, fishdata$Number,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. I attempted to substitute various values to attempt to make it work, but no luck. I was having trouble following what was happening, so I changed some of the original lines of code. Can you adapt your code to work with the new? I think it'll help me learn R quicker. Thanks.